# What's the difference between (const_cast<char*> and without?

Tags: c++, imgui

I'm having a hard time understanding the difference between those two commands

```cpp
        char name[0x36];
        sprintf_s(name, "Some Text (%d%% Water) [%dm]", amount, dist);
        Drawing::RenderText(const_cast<char*>(name), screen, cfg.visuals.ships.textCol);
```

and

```cpp
        char name[0x36];
        sprintf_s(name, "Some Text (%d%% Water) [%dm]", amount, dist);
        Drawing::RenderText(name, screen, cfg.visuals.ships.textCol);
```

and here's the RenderText func:

```cpp
void xD::Renderer::Drawing::RenderText(const char* text, const FVector2D& pos, const ImVec4& color, const bool outlined = true, const bool centered = true)
{
    if (!text) return;
    auto ImScreen = *reinterpret_cast<const ImVec2*>(&pos);
    if (centered)
    {
        auto size = ImGui::CalcTextSize(text);
        ImScreen.x -= size.x * 0.5f;
        ImScreen.y -= size.y;
    }
    auto window = ImGui::GetCurrentWindow();

    if (outlined) 
    { 
        window->DrawList->AddText(nullptr, 0.f, ImVec2(ImScreen.x - 1.f, ImScreen.y + 1.f), ImGui::GetColorU32(IM_COL32_BLACK), text); 
    }

    window->DrawList->AddText(nullptr, 0.f, ImScreen, ImGui::GetColorU32(color), text);

}
```

Im working with ImGui

Comment: That doesn't seem like correct use of `const_cast` to me. Where did you see this?

Comment: Practically there's no difference and the cast is not needed. The compiler will implicitly convert the (decayed) pointer to the string to `const`.

Comment: On another note, it's very unusual to use hexadecimal literals for array sizes, unless they depend on some binary value that are easier to understand in hexadecimal. And why are you using C-style strings (`char` arrays and the non-standard `sprintf_s` (which you use wrong anyway)) instead of C++ `std::string`? Remember that `std::string` have a `c_str()` function to get a C-style "string" (pointer to the first character of a null-terminated array).

Comment: `reinterpret_cast`-ing into `ImVec2` is technically undefined. It would be better to define a constructor and a conversion operator in `ImVec2` to convert to and from your vector, ImGui has a config macro that lets you do that.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat could you show me it? Discord maybe? Kierak#8418

Comment: Nope, no discord. Check [imconfig.h](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/master/imconfig.h), `IM_VEC2_CLASS_EXTRA`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What's the difference between (const_cast<char*> and without?

The difference is that in one case the conversion is implicit and in the other case the conversion is explicit. There is no other difference.

Comment: that means that I shouldn't use (const_cast<char*> since it may cause unwanted problems/compiler issues?

Comment: @noone in this case - it was just a waste of typing as the two produce identical results.

Comment: @noone You shouldn't use casts when you don't understand why you're using them or whether you should use them. In this case, you don't need to use it, but you can.